# What does the first explicit lifetime specifier on an impl mean?

Tags: rust, lifetime

There are three different lifetime specifiers on an impl:

```
impl<'a> Type<'a> {
    fn my_function(&self) -> &'a u32 {
        self.x
    }
}
```

`Type<'a>` states that *there is* a lifetime in this impl declaration. The one on the return type `-> &'a u32` states that the variable that receives the return value should not die before...before what? Before the object of type `Type` dies?

What's the difference to this:

```
impl TextEditor {
    //Other methods omitted ...

    pub fn get_text<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a String {
        return &self.text;
    }
}
```

Here it says for the return type to not die before the lifetime of `&'a self` ends.

Does the last one declare only a lifetime to this one method and the other one declares a lifetime to every method (and associate function?) in the impl declaration?

Comment: `Type<'a>`might very well contain something that depends on `'a`. Eg. on `slice::Iter<'a, T>`, `'a` is the lifetime of the corresponding slice. [`as_slice(&self) -> &'a [T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#method.as_slice) can then retrieve it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`'a` is a ***lifetime parameter*** in both cases. That's a kind of generic parameter, so each use of `Type` or each use of `get_text` can pick a different "value" for that generic parameter. Actual lifetimes are never picked explicitly by the programmer, except when you use `'static`.

The compiler will infer what `'a` should be for each value of `Type` or each use of `get_text`.

`impl<'a>` introduces a new lifetime parameter for the whole impl block. It is then used in the type: `impl<'a> Type<'a> { .. }`

Exactly what `'a` means depends on how it is used in the definition of `Type`. From your example, I guess that `Type` is this:

```
struct Type<'a> {
    x: &'a u32,
}
```

This definition reads: For every lifetime `'a`, define Type to contain a reference `x: &'a u32`. So `Type` is generic and can store a reference with any lifetime.

`impl<'a> Type<'a> { .. }` reads: For every lifetime `'a`, define methods for the type `Type<'a>`.

Since we now know the struct definition of `Type`, we know that the `'a` parameter inside the impl block is always equal to the lifetime of the reference in `Type`'s x field.

> The one on the return type -> &'a u32 tells that the
>   variable which is receiving the return value should not die
>   before...before what? Before the object of type Type dies?

`'a` is the lifetime of the reference stored inside a value of `Type<'a>`, and it has no other relation to the Type value itself. The only rule is that `'a` must outlive the Type value itself, because it is not allowed to store a reference past its end of life. So in fact, we can hold on to that `&'a u32` until at least the point when the `Type` value dies, and maybe longer.

---

```
impl TextEditor {
    //Other methods omitted ...

    pub fn get_text<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a String {
        return &self.text;
    }
}
```

This is really common. `&self` is a reference to the self value — a borrow — and the method `get_text` is again a generic item. It has one generic parameter — a lifetime parameter.

It reads, for any lifetime `'a`, borrow self as the reference `&'a self` (reference of that lifetime) and return a reference to String with the same lifetime.

The use of the same parameter on both the input `&self` and the output `&String` means that they are connected and Rust will treat self as borrowed as long as the returned reference to String is alive.

Again, the method `get_text` is generic, and the compiler will pick a "value" for `'a` for each use of the method. It's a method that can return variously long borrows of a String, depending on how long you allow it to borrow `self`. Sometimes it picks a long lifetime so that you can hold onto the returned `&String` for a long time. Some uses of `get_text` will use a shorter lifetime, if you don't use the returned value at all.

In this case, since we see that `&'a String` is tied directly to a borrow `&'a self` of a `TextEditor` value, we know that we can only keep the String reference around at most as long as we can hold a borrow of the `TextEditor` value.

Comment: Thinking of <'a> notation as generics was an "aha" moment for me. Don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 29):

Paraphrasing the Rust code:

```
impl<'a>
```

"If you give me a lifetime..."  (the compiler normally supplies this based on context when using the type)

```
         Type<'a> {
```

"...I'll describe how to implement `Type<'a>`".  So `Type` probably contains references (which need a lifetime).

```
    fn my_function(&self) -> &'a u32 {
```

"...and given a reference to `Type<'a>`, you call `my_function()` to get a reference to a `u32` with lifetime `'a`."  Note that the lifetime of the `&self` reference is not directly tied to `'a`; it can be shorter (but usually not longer than `'a`, since a type can't outlive contained references).

In the second case:

```
impl TextEditor {
```

"Here's how to implement a non-lifetime parametric type `TextEditor`..."

```
pub fn get_text<'a>
```

"Given a lifetime `'a` which you can choose (it's an input parameter)..."

```
                   (&'a self)
```

"...and a reference to a `TextEditor` which lives for at least `'a`.."

```
                             -> &'a String {
```

"...you can call the `get_text` method and receive a borrowed reference to a `String` which lives for the same time."

In more practical terms, this really means that the `String` is reborrowed directly from the `TextEditor` - as long as that `String` reference is alive, the `&self` borrow is considered to still be active and you won't be able to take any `&mut` references.

Comment: thanks, this was incredibly helpful! I find I understand most of Rust's concepts in isolation but often struggle when they're put together in practice. translating terse syntax into explanatory prose is a great way to understand what's going on. I wish read-along code examples were more of a thing :)

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the question has to do with the scoping of `'a`:

| situation | `'a` scoping |
| --- | --- |
| `impl<'a> { fn }` | `'a` may be used for any function inside |
| `impl { fn<'a> }` | `'a` is specific to each function |

In both cases, `'a` is a generic lifetime parameter. *For either function, there is **no difference** in the semantics of `'a`.*

This table illustrates the scoping difference, but it doesn't highlight the practical benefits of specifying lifetimes at the `impl` level. In situations where you have multiple methods that need to work with the same lifetime constraints, 'hoisting' the lifetime syntax to the `impl` level establishes a consistent constraint across all methods in that block.